# How to get all elements within a div and putan onclick on them using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to be able to grab all the bubbles inside the "bubble game" div and put an onclick on them so that they dissapear(delete from the page) when being clicked. I have tried making a variable in javascript that contains all bubbles in the div and then put an onclick on them but it doesn't seem to work. Preferably not using jquery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bubbles</title>
<link href="bubbles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bubbles.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/java.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--background bubbles-->
<div id="b-blue" class="b" data-speed="1"></div>
<div id="b-green" class="b" data-speed="2"></div>
<div id="b-red" class="b" data-speed="4"></div>

<!--bubble text-->
<div id="bText">
    B<br />U<br />B<br />B<br />L<br />E<br />S<br />!
</div>

<!--bubble game-->
<div id="bubbleGame">
    <!-- <div class="bubble"></div> -->
</div>

<!--bubble score and reset-->
<div id="bottomCorner">
    <div id="reload">refresh...</div>
    <div id="score">0</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>



body{
background:black;   
}

#bText{
width:300px;
float:left;
height:auto;
color:white;
font-size:300px;
text-align:center;
font-family:'spilt_inkregular', Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
position:relative;
z-index:10;
opacity:0.8;
}

.b{
width:100%;
height:1000%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;     
}

#b-blue{ background:url(images/b-blue.png); }
#b-red{ background:url(images/b-red.png); }
#b-green{ background:url(images/b-green.png); }

#bubbleGame{
width:75%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
right:2%;
top:0;
}

.bubble{
background:url(images/b-white.png);
background-size:cover;  
position:absolute;
}


window.onload = bubblegame;

function bubble(){
var bubbleburst = document.querySelectorAll("#bubbleGame");

for(var i=0; i<bubbleburst.length; i++){
    bubbleburst[i].onclick = burst; 
}

}

function burst(){

alert("hi");    
}
```

Comment: Where is the javascript code you said you tried? Please include it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bubbleGame").on("click", ".bubble", function() {
    $(this).hide();
  })
});
```

If you would like to remove the element from the DOM, use $(this).remove(), instead of $(this).hide().

Comment: Think you mean $(this)

Comment: Thank you Ryven - edited to reflect correct syntax now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `event-Delegation`:

I prepared a simplified [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f4wT/1/)

```
document.getElementById("bubblegame").addEventListener("click", function(element){
    var target=element.target;
    if(target.id==='bubblegame') return;
    target.style.display='none';
});
```

In this case, you do not add `eventListener` to the bubbles itself, but to the parent div.
When an element is clicked, the event bubbles up to the "catching" div, where a central dispatcher is waiting for that event. So you have the advantage of having *one* handler to deal with all events. For more information about delegation of events, take a look [here](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using jQuery:

```
$("#bubbleGame > .bubble").click(function() {
   $(this).hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

without Jquery:

```
var bubbles = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble');
for (var bubble of bubbles) {
  bubble.onclick = deleteBubble
}

function deleteBubble() {
 this.parentNode.removeChild(this);   
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tZqdr/)

Comment: Thank you. This is somewhat how I am trying to accomplish it. However, I still can't seem to make this way work.

Comment: No. This is the javascript code im trying.

    function bubble(){
 var bubbleburst = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble');
 
    for(var i=0; i<bubbleburst.length; i++){
  bubbleburst[i].onclick = burst; 
 }
}

function burst(){
 alert("hi");
}

im just trying to get an alert to see if the onclick works and so far nothing.

Comment: if you create your bubbles dynamically ? your code seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/tZqdr/2/

Comment: I wasn't the one who created the bubbles. They are floating around on the screen. Here is the make bubbles function:


function makeBubbles(){
 var i;
 for(i=0;i<20;i++){  
  var newBubble = document.createElement("div");
  $(newBubble).addClass("bubble");
  $("#bubbleGame").append(newBubble);  
  randomize(newBubble);
 }
}

Comment: maybe when you try to attach event on your bubbles they dosen't exist yet. I suggest you to consider @ThomasJunk method. attach an event on the parent and check the target.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bubble").click(function() {
    $(".bubble").hide();
  })
});
```

Comment: Calling the selector twice is not too effective... Why not use `this`?

Comment: I not sure if using `this` would make all the bubbles disappear.

Comment: I don't think he wants all of them to go away, but even then, you could run the selector once, and save the results into a variable.